# Exporting Illustrator to SVG, Colours, Gradients and Opacity wrongly displayed

Tags: svg, export, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

I'm having trouble creating an SVG (for web use) from an illustrator file sent by the design agency. The SVG exported doesn't look like the same, specially because the affected areas are suppose to look like shadowed areas of human characters. The art created is quite complex and I'm not authorised to show it, but I'm just putting here one of the elements that replicates the issue.

[image]

original .ai file + exported .svg in this zip: http://we.tl/AdJPqFqQd1

I've also saved it in .eps and tried exporting, but it didn't make a difference

I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't be too hurtful considering that there are many elements in the original artwork like this shape and most of them have different colours and shapes.

I tried to access the CSS within the SVG but I couldn't manage to change the gradient.

Using Illustrator CC 2015 I've tried exporting with all the different options (unless I missed some special combination, which I do not believe)

Hopefully and with a lot of luck, I would like to find someone who came across this problem before and knows how to deal with it. If you could try it yourself, you would be aware of this issue and I would appreciate it very much. Thanks

Comment: I had a look in the SVG (I don't care much for illustrator so dont own a copy) and everything seemed right, So on a hunch I replaced the Mask url that was a jpg with a png. I added an alpha channel that was just the inverse of the original jpg Black and white image and then it looked a lot like the original. So the problem is in the mask image, the lighter colour in the SVG is coming from the white pixels in the mask.

Comment: Thanks for this observation, @Blindman67. As it is very hard to go through all the shapes I found that editing the most problematic css classes was easier. Changing 5 properties of 3 classes revealed most of the missing colours and now the difference between the original is not easily noticeable. The properties changed were opacity and fill colours. This is not optimal of course.. But did the trick for now.